# How can I make a pool with pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm making my library, and just when I thought understanding the pointers syntax, I just get confused, search on the web and get even more confused.

Basically I want to make a pool, here is what I actually want to do:

[image: context]

*the following points must be respected :*

- when I add an object to the pool, the pointers of the current array to the objects are
  added to a new array of pointers + 1 (to contain the new object).
- the new array is pointed by "objects" of my foo structure.
- the old array is free'ing.
- when I call the cleanup function, all the object in the pool are
  free'd

---

*How should I define my structure ?*

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
    (???)objects
} foo;
foo *the_pool;
```

here's the code to manage my pool :

```
void myc_pool_init ()
{
    the_pool = (???)malloc(sizeof(???));
    the_pool->n = 0;
    the_pool->objects = NULL;
}

void myc_push_in_pool (void* object)
{
    if (object != NULL) {
        int i;
        (???)new_pointers;

        the_pool->n++;
        new_pointers = (???)malloc(sizeof(???)*the_pool->n);

        for (i = 0; i < the_pool->n - 1; ++i) {
            new_pointers[i] = (the_pool->objects)[i]; // that doesn't work (as I'm not sure how to handle it)
        }
        new_array[i] = object;

        free(the_pool->objects);
        the_pool->objects = new_array; // that must be wrong
    }
}

void myc_pool_cleanup ()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < the_pool->n; ++i)
        free((the_pool->objects)[i]); // as in myc_push_in_pool, it doesn't work
    free(the_pool->objects);
    free(the_pool);
}
```

**Note: the type of objects added to the pool are not known in advance, so i should handles all pointers as void**
any feedback would be very welcomed.

Comment: If C had this kind of type generic programming, don't you think [qsort](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html) would use that instead of callback functions and the width argument?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan That book says on the first page "Only object-orientation permits code reuse between projects". Utter nonsense! This author is very confused. Please explain abstraction in Haskell, if code reuse isn't possible without object orientation.

Comment: Take a look at Ted Jensen's ["A tutorial on arrays and pointers in C"](http://home.earthlink.net/~momotuk/pointers.pdf), and perhaps review Steve Summit's ["Introductory C programming"](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html). Dated, but should be required reading before asking here anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straight answer to your question would be: use `void *`. This type is very powerful as it allows you to put any kind of pointer in your pool. However, it's up to you to do the correct casts when retrieving a `void *` pointer from your pool.

Your struct would look like this

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
    (void **)objects
} foo;
foo *the_pool;
```

As in, an array of pointers.

Your malloc:

```
new_pointers = (void **)malloc(sizeof(void *)*the_pool->n);
```

There is an performance issue here. You could simply allocate an array of a fixed size, and only reallocate if the number of elements exceeds a predefined load factor (= number used/ max size)

Also, instead of allocating a new pointer each time you add something to your pool, you could just use `realloc` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)

```
the_pool->objects = (void **)realloc(the_pool->objects, the_pool->n* sizeof(void*));
```

Realloc tries to increase the current allocated area, without the need to copy everything. Only if the function cannot increase the allocated area contiguously will it allocate a new area and copy everything.

Comment: No need to cast the return value from malloc.

Comment: I truly thank you for this answer, now I understand the use of pointers. and thanks for the realloc tip.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you already answered your "What should the type of foo.objects be?" question: `void *objects;`, malloc already returns `void *`. Your struct needs to store the `size_t item_size;`, too. `n` should probably also be a `size_t`.

```
typedef struct {
    size_t item_count;
    size_t item_size;
    void *objects;
} foo;
foo *the_pool;
```

You *could* use a home-grown loop, but I'd consider memcpy to be a more convenient way to copy your old items to your new space, and the new item to it's new space.

Dereferencing a `void *` is a constraint violation, as is pointer arithmetic on a `void *`, so `new_pointers` will need to be a different type. You need a type that points to objects of the right size. You could use an array of the right number of `unsigned char`, like so:

```
// new_pointers is a pointer to array of the_pool->item_size unsigned chars.
unsigned char (*new_pointers)[the_pool->item_size] = malloc(the_pool->item_count * sizeof *new_pointers);

// copy the old items
memcpy(new_pointers, the_pool->objects, the_pool->item_count * sizeof *new_pointers);

// copy the new items
memcpy(new_pointers + the_pool->item_count, object, sizeof *new_pointers);
```

Remember, *free()* is *only* for pointers returned by malloc(), and there should be a one-to-one correspondence: Each malloc() should be free()d. Look how you malloc: `new_pointers = malloc(sizeof(???)*the_pool->n);` ... What makes you think you need a loop (in myc_pool_cleanup) to free each item, when you can free them all in one foul swoop?

You *could* use realloc, but you otherwise seem to be handling malloc/memcpy/free *in myc_push_in_pool* flawlessly. Lots of people tend to mess up when writing realloc code.